# How can I add SlingSafeMethodsServlet to this AEM sample project through maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, aem

I'm using the Eclipse AEM plugin and am importing a sample project. Unfortunately, this sample project does not contain certain dependencies that the accompanying tutorial asks you to use, so I'd like to add those dependencies.

I'd like to end up being able to access this class: 
https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/servlets/SlingSafeMethodsServlet.html

In my project's pom.xml, I have this included:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.2</version>
    </dependency
```

After doing `mvn clean install`, I can see that the .jar is saved to the /target directory. However, if I go to add this as a library in Properties > Java Build Path > Add JARs, I don't see it.

I'm able to add it by going to "Add External JARs", but this seems to bypass maven.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you don't need these downloaded in your target folder. Most of the sling, osgi, aem dependencies are available in AEM instance thus no need to package.

You could simple configure your project to pull all dependencies from .m2 folder. All these dependencies should be set to `<scope>provided</scope>`. Refer to sample pom.xml [here](https://github.com/ameeshtrikha/aem-parent/blob/master/pom.xml), this one uses Uber.jar so doesn't specify the sling dependencies explicitly.

Also make sure that your project has maven local repo configured to `.m2/repositories`

UPDATE

[image: Java Build Path]

Comment: How do you configure the project's maven local repo?

Comment: In your eclipse->preferences->Java->BuildPath->Class Path Variables

See snapshot above.